# sqlite3/C transaction begin end -- overflow?

Tags: c, memory-management, sqlite, transactions

In C on an embedded system (where memory is an issue), trying to optimize performance, **multiple inserts are combined into larger transactions**.

Intuitively, SQLITE must keep the unsent transactions in a cache somewhere in the limited memory.

- Is it possible to have too many inserts between two calls of 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' and 'END TRANSACTION'? Can the cache overflow?
- Or, does sqlite3 take care of it and initiate a transaction before a overflow happens?
- If the cache may overflow, what is the best strategy to call BEGIN/END?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any changes you make are written to the database file. To support rollbacks, the old contents of the changed database pages are saved in the journal file.
When you commit a transaction, the journal file is just deleted; when you roll back a transaction, those pages are written back.

So there is not limit on the size of the data in a transaction, as long as you have enough disk space.

(The cache can help with avoiding some writes, but it works transparently and does not affect the semantics of your code.)

Comment: So the 'transaction-delayed insert' is nothing more than writing into a journal file, not into some memory?

Comment: What do you mean with "delayed"?

Comment: Delayed: 'begin transaction', 'insert', 'insert', 'insert' ... 'end transaction'. That is, the 'insert' into the database does not happen immediately, but upon call to 'end transaction'.

Comment: Other connections cannot observe this because the DB is locked. Actual delays happen only because of the cache.